# How do i make sure that both Producer and Consumer threads run infinitely and one after another?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

How do I make sure that both Producer and Consumer functions run infinitely and one after another? For example: First, I want the user to enter the array and then the consumer function prints the entered array and then again asks the user to input the array.

```
/*  Headers  */


pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond,cond1;
void *producer(void *arg);
void *consumer(void *arg);
static int n;
int consumerFlag[100];

void *producer(void *arg) 
{

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);        

  while(1)
    {
      printf("\n Enter no of terms");
      scanf("%d",&n);
      int i; 
      printf("\n Enter consumer flag array");
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
      scanf(" %d",&consumerFlag[i]);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);           
        }
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);    
      usleep(1000);
    }


}


void *consumer(void *arg) 
{
  int i;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); 
  printf("\nConsumer Function"); 
  while(1)
    {

      printf("\nConsumer thread waiting"); 

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {    
          printf("\nConsumerFlag %d = %d", i, consumerFlag[i]); 
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);         

        }          

    }

}

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,0);
  pthread_cond_init(&cond,0);   
  pthread_t pThread, cThread;
  pthread_create(&pThread, 0, producer, 0);
  pthread_create(&cThread, 0, consumer,0);   
  pthread_join(pThread,NULL);
  pthread_join(cThread, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
  return 0;
}
```

First, I want the user to enter the array and then the consumer function prints the entered array and then again asks the user to input the array.

Comment: Use two condition flags, one for the producer to signal the consumer that it has work to consume, and one for the consumer to signal the producer that it is ready for more work.

Comment: You have one call to `pthread_mutex_lock` and multiple to `pthread_mutex_unlock`. Use them correctly: loc to get access to common resources, unlock to alow others access

Comment: One clarification required: Do you want producer to produce complete array before conusmer start consuming? OR do you want producer and consumer to work on different array indices parallelly?

Comment: I want the Producer to produce the whole array before the consumer starts consuming. @MayurK

Comment: @DevanshuTripathi: OK. Then you dont need consumerFlag[100]. Only one conumerflag and one producerflag are sufficient. However, you need to use two condition variables - one each for producer and consumer.

Comment: Actually, I want the producer to produce an array of a particular size and then the consumer should consume the array and after this, the producer should again produce some array of some size and the consumer should print it on the screen. @MayurK

Comment: @DevanshuTripathi Oops! Sorry! consumerFlag[100] is the actual data buffer :( I thought it is just a flag.

Comment: @MayurK Can you help with the modifications needed in the code?

Comment: @DevanshuTripathi Sure. But first you need to read about pthread_mutex. The usage is completely wrong in your code (Comment #2). Also, you can make attempt to the suggestion given in comment #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few major issues in your code.

1. A mutex can be unlocked by a thread only if the thread has locked it before. In your code, mutex is locked outside loop function and unlocked inside the loop. It will give undefined behavior.
2. Consumer function is doing signal_wait() before entering loop. I think you have assumed that the producer and consumer threads start almost simultaneously and producer would not signal before consumer locks the mutex. This is wrong. **You should assume that threads get scheduled in a random order** and handle all possible cases.
3. You are not notifying producer when consumer has consumed data completely. There is no signalling mechanism from consumer to producer.
4. You are notifying consumer when producer has produced data completely. But consumer is not waiting outside while loop. It means, only once it may get notification.
5. In producer, the condition_signal is after unlocking mutex, which is wrong. Signal should be called with mutex locked.

So in producer, you need to produce data, send signal to consumer and wait for confirmation from consumer that data is consumed. You need to set a flag additionally to take the case where producer thread acquire lock before consumer thread into account. In this case, consumer would not have entered the while loop when producer sends signal. So consumer can not catch the signal.

```
void *producer(void *arg) 
{     
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);        

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n Enter no of terms");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int i; 
        printf("\n Enter consumer flag array");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            scanf(" %d",&consumerFlag[i]);
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  //Should not be unlocked in loop         
        }
        data_produced_flag = 1; //A flag to indicate data is ready. Should be initialized to 0 before thread creation. It is required if producer produces before consumer thread goes to pthread_cond_wait()
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_producer); //Should send signal with mutex locked
        //usleep(1000); //Not required as it is going to wait for signal from consumer

        pthread_cond_wait(&cond_consumer, &mutex); //Wait for confirmation that data is consumed
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
}
```

In consumer function, you should check if the data is already produced. If not produced, wait for for signal from producer. When data is available, consume and signal producer to get fresh data.

```
void *consumer(void *arg) 
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    //pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);  //Wait inside loop
    printf("\nConsumer Function"); 
    while(1)
    {
        if(0 == data_produced_flag) 
        {
            printf("\nConsumer thread waiting"); 
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_producer, &mutex); //Wait for signal from producer
        }
        //else
        //{
            //Data is already produced. No need to wait.
        //}

        //Data is available for consumption
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {    
            printf("\nConsumerFlag %d = %d", i, consumerFlag[i]); 
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);    //We are in the process of consumption. Don't unlock mutex.
        }
        data_produced_flag = 0; //Reset the flag. Ready for new data.
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_consumer); //Indicate that data is consumed
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
}
```